# How to create database and add 2 table in SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am using SQLite ADO.NET Provider.

I want to create a database with 2 tables via code in vb.net .

Please provide code for the same.

I am using VS 2010 Winforms, working under XP SP3 Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SQLiteConnection's `CreateFile()` method.

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("c:\\mydatabasefile.db3")
```

More info on the [System.Data.SQLite forums](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/77.aspx)

You can then send ad-hoc `CREATE TABLE` statements to the engine:

```
dim myTableCreate as String = 
                    "CREATE TABLE MyTable(CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, 
                     FirstName VARCHAR(25));"

cmd.CommandText = myTableCreate
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

[More on SQLite `CREATE TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: Are you sure this is right?, I am getting a lot of errors when I try to create a table.

Comment: Is it necessary to put a semi-colon at the end of the 1st statement

Comment: I don't think the semi-colon is strictly necessary or required. It's a command terminator. As for the CREATE statement, here's another example site: http://www.devdaily.com/android/sqlite-create-table-insert-syntax-examples

Comment: a semi-colon is good practice and is in the ANSI standard for SQL statements..  as of MSSQL2014 (??) it will be required after every statement..

Comment: @Ads the semi-colon is *not* required in TSQL in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Actually @p.campbell you are correct, I wish I could find where I read that it was coming, maybe it was in 2016, but as always it will be a "configurable item" to not tick off too many people by making them adhere to the standards.  :-P

Answer (score 1):

For those who need this, here is an updated working code...

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("c:\mydatabasefile.db3")
Using Query As New SQLiteCommand()
    Connection.ConnectionString ="DataSource=c:\mydatabasefile.db3;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
    Connection.Open()
        With Query 
            .Connection = Connection
            .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable(CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, FirstName VARCHAR(25))"
        End With
Query.ExecuteNonQuery()
Connection.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: I think `DataSource` should be `Data Source`. Thanks anyway.