# How do you set up a simple local SQLite database in vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, vb.net-2010, system.data.sqlite

I'm doing a school project using Visual Studios 2010 Express and I'm coding in vb.NET. I have fair knowledge of the language but as soon as I tried to implement a SQLite database in my project, I was hit with complicated syntax I've never before seen. So, I searched online and couldn't find helpful tutorials on SQLite specifically for vb.NET. Nobody has made videos on YouTube for it and most websites just show code and expect people to know it. Since I'm doing a write-up as well, I need to understand each line of code inside out, so it would be nice if someone could give me an in-depth guide on how to set up a SQLite database on my vb.NET project.

PS: I've already installed the References like ADO.NET and System.Data.SQLite.dll

Thanks!

Comment: By _set up a SQLite database_ do you mean how to create the database and define the tables or how to distribute a premade database file?

Comment: Pretty vague.  How can we possibly know what "complicated syntax" you are talking about?

Comment: @Steve I mean the first option so, "how to create the database and define the tables".

Comment: @Plutonix http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814743/Create-ADO-NET-SQLite-Database-Programmatically-by

Comment: This is in C# but I think it is easy to understand and recreate in VB.NET http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-create-and-connect-to-an-sqlite-database-in-c/

Comment: Got also this one in VB.NET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106771/how-to-create-database-and-add-2-table-in-sqlite

Comment: @steve thanks for the comments. From my understanding, you create the database in vb.NET and you create the tables using SQL. I understood the second link and now am trying to implement it but the first one was hard to convert to vb.NET.

Comment: Of course this is not mandatory. You could always create a database in your office and distribute it with your application
At the end of the story SQLite database are just a single file and in any case you need to distribute the DLL used to access that file

Comment: @Steve The thing is, I'm doing a school project which is simple (create a database and add things to it). Everyone is used to using Access but the Exam Report said that they are starting to drop marks to people who us access due to its easiness to create a database. So I found SQLite to be considered "easy" and I started researching. But then, I really don't understand most of the lines. Plus, I need to do a write-up which requires explaining what every line of code does in detail. I'm just looking for a kind person to explain to me how to create the database and define the tables in vb.net :)